# How can i search for an specified result[key + value] in a json with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a discord bot, which works with the shoppy api, right now.
My target is to filter the respone of the shoppy api and get a value and key.
All i have done is parsing the request result into an json object.
This is my code - i replaces sensitive data

```js
request("https://shoppy.gg/api/v1/orders/"+args[0], options ,function(error, response, body) {
      if (*1) {
        console.log("Result: " + body);
        var info = JSON.parse(body);

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor("#756cff")
        .setDescription("Valid order ID. You have been given customer role!")
        .setImage(client.user.displayAvatarURL);

      message.channel.send(embed);

      }else{
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor("#756cff")
        .setDescription("Please enter a valid ID!")
        .setImage(client.user.displayAvatarURL);

      message.channel.send(embed);;
      }
    });
```

So i want that *1 checks if the result is {"status":false,"message":"Requested resource not found"}.
How can i do this?

Comment: would parsing the json before testing what it contains fix the problem? The code seems to be in the wrong order. Note you may need to check the `error` parameter of the call back before attempting to parse the body.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t understand your question but if you need the “key” and “value” of Object you can use Object.entries(objectName)
And if you need to find “Value” of Object and you know the Object’s name you can use: objectName.key or objectName[“key”]

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple if statement to check if the property and value are in the object or not

```js
var obj={as:534,dsad:54,htyhty:65,delivered:1}
obj.delivered==1?console.log(true):console.log(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! But as i said i have not an actual file, i have only the json parse from the response of the api